# The function of a capacitor with the fluorescent lamp

Tags: capacitor

What is the function of the capacitor across the supply to the fluorescent lamp when it is used?

Comment: Where have you seen a capacitor across the supply to a fluorescent lamp?

Comment: There are two caps. One is inside the starter for EMI suppression during the inductive kick. There is also another capacitor for power factor correction between the line and neutral. See here for basic info: https://books.google.dk/books?id=MP8sCgAAQBAJ&pg=PA110&dq=%22fluorescent+lamp%22+%22the+choke+limits%22&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwikru6s1sTZAhUBDuwKHRiMDJcQ6AEIKTAA#v=onepage&q&f=false

Comment: I recommend you enhance your question with a small schematic. So it will be of more use to other users having the same question.

Answer (score 1):

[image]

*Figure 1. A typical fluorescent lamp circuit with capacitor on mains input. Source: [Illumination - types of lamps](https://www.slideshare.net/vijayraskar501/types-of-lamps).*

Fluorescent lamps form an inductive load on the AC mains supply. As a result large installations of such lamps suffer a poor power factor and resultant voltage drop. Adding a capacitor to each lamp corrects the power factor bringing it back close to unity (1.0). This solves the problem of associated voltage drop and also, for large energy users, eliminates power factor surcharge on the bills - for that part of the load at least.

It is possible to omit the capacitor on the individual lamps and to centralise them in the switch room and automatically switch in as many as required to keep the power factor within acceptable limits.

Comment: these are old fashioned heater FL tubes with 4 independent pins.  Obsoleted pretty much with more efficient tubes where both end tubes are shorted.  The starter switch is heat sensitive and emits an EMI pulse that interferes with radios and video cards with long cables. So the cap serves to reduce spectrum.

Answer (score 1):

Fluorescent lamps, like spark gaps, have negative resistance.   This makes the lamp very likely to build up an oscillation, causing radio interference.   The capacitor, in addition to the internal RF
resistance in the ballast choke, damps such oscillation.

There's
a capacitor across the points of a classical auto distributor's points
(which are a spark gap), for similar reasons.   With other components,
Marconi made early practical radio transmitters powered by ... a spark gap.

Answer (score 0):

Not any of it exactly correct I'm afraid. If you take the breaker points in the car, the release of current to the coil primary when the switch opens causes the immediate field collapse that will generate the HV spark. If you draw out the circuit (remember it's an auto transformer without isolation between primary & secondary), you will see that without the capacitor there is no direct earth connection. That's what the "condenser" provides. This is ringing ac at HF. It also stops the propensity therefore to arc across the points as they are by-passed by it. Low reactance to ac.
The fluorescent is a different issue. For PF correction yes but not required for operation. The lamp must record correctly the power it is taking from the mains. The inductor (choke) spoils that for inductive motorised recorders (The company meter). You want to pay don't you? !!